# How To Move A Label To Right?

Tags: c#

I want to move a label ( named Label2 ) to the right by pressing a button and when I press the button again I want it to move again ( Hope You Understand )

This is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 28;
        x++;
        label2.Location = new Point(x, 63);
    }
```

But it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could just go with `label2.Left++;`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using a local `int x`, so it will be reset to 28 each time you click the button.

Move the declaration of `x` outside the `button3_Click()` method so that 'x' is a field. Then it will retain its value between each button click.

Obviously you will need to give it a better name; perhaps `currentLabelLeft`.

Comment: So Full Code It will Be How ?

Answer (score 1):

This will move it right by 1 pixel each time:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = label2.Location.X;
        x++;
        label2.Location = new Point(x, 63);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two css classes and set them as follows (if you have to set it from code behind):

```
label2.CssClass = "move_to_right"
```